# How to make Unit test passed with use Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How I understand Mockito.mock create the stub of the service (or another object).

I have simple handler:

```
public class Handler
    {
        private HttpSender sender;
        public Handler(BigInteger sessiongId) {
            RequestHelper helper = RequestHelper.getInstance();
            String requestAsText = helper.getCurrentRequest(sessiongId);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(requestAsText);
            run(stringBuilder);
            sender = SenderGenerator.getInstance().create(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        public void run(StringBuilder str) {
            str.delete(0, 2);
        }
    }
```

How I can pass test for this handler with use Mockito?

```
public class HandlerTest
{
    @Test
    public void testRun()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("1234");
        Handler handler = Mockito.mock(Handler.class);
        handler.run(str);
        Assert.assertEquals("34", str);
    }
}
```

The actual result of this test is 1234 ? Why ?

Comment: Because you replaced the thing you're supposedly testing with a mock that does nothing?

Comment: How I can make the test with functional like a method run() ?

Comment: Just *don't* mock the thing you're testing? It's not clear why you think you need to mock anything here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is example. I have the service instead handler, which have dependencies with another services. And I need to test one method on this service.

Comment: So you mock those other services, the collaborators, not the one you're actually trying to test. In the example you've provided there's no need for mocking; if that's not representative, *give one that is*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I add handler with dependancies.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to test the run method? How I can do it?

Comment: I think you need to read up on "dependency inversion" - also the run method doesn't need any of the complicated stuff the constructor sets up, so maybe this could be refactored entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your haldler object in the test method is a mock-object and not a real object the method call handler.run(str) will not do anything as long as you don't tell it what to do.

So a solution would be to tell the mock object to call the real method like this:

```
public class HandlerTest {
    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("1234");
        Handler handler = Mockito.mock(Handler.class);
        when(handler.run(any(StringBuilder.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
        handler.run(str);
        Assert.assertEquals("34", str.toString());//add toString here, because you are comparing a String to a StringBuilder
    }
}
```

Another way of testing this method would be to make it static so you dont even need to mock anything:

```
public class Handler {
    public Handler(BigInteger sessiongId) {
        //...
    }
    public static void run(StringBuilder str) {
        str.delete(0, 2);
    }
}
```

And your test method would look like this:

```
public class HandlerTest {
    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("1234");
        Handler.run(str);
        Assert.assertEquals("34", str.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1. You have mocked the very class you want to test. And you haven't defined any specific behaviour for the mock either. So the call to the test method itself is skipped. You may have to think over what was the purpose of mocking?
2. You are comparing a StringBuilder object with a String, that needs to be corrected too.